# How to filter the products based on product_type, that are retrieved using collectionByHandle in shopify storefront graphQL api?

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

In our app, we are displaying the list of collections from the shopify store. When user click on any of collection, it will redirect to product list, where all the products of that clicked collection will be displayed.

Here is the sample query which I used to get the products list of particular collection :

```
{
  collectionByHandle(handle: "") {
    products(first: 10) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I want filtering on products list. I want to display products base on product_type. But there is no any option to filter the products.

`query` option only available when you retrieve simple products listing using this query :

```
{
  products(query: "product_type:casual-things", first: 10) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        title
        productType
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But, this `query` option not available on `products` node of `collectionByHandle`.

Can, anyone help me how to implement filter option using Shopify storefront graphQL api in `collectionByHandle` query ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No, I have not found a solution yet. I skiped that product filter feature.

Answer (score 0):

The `products` connection doesn't have a query argument. You have basically access to fetching all products within that `collectionByHandle` and then filtering them client-side. You must have to use `liquid` for these types of nested features.